# AoG: NodeJS to DialogFlow User Entities

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I've come across this User Entities on DialogFlow v2.

https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions.entityTypes/create

Does anyone know or can point out some example code on how to use this to pass custom data back to DialogFlow's User Entities?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the ***resource.js*** in this directory

[https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2/tree/master/samples](http://DialogFlow%20Samples)